# difference between save: and processPendingChanges: in CoreData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I have an NSManagedObjectContext, i make a couple of changes to the model and then... to "commit" the transactions, what's the difference between doing:

```
[context save:&error];
```

and

```
[context processPendingChanges];
```

It seems they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In a nutshell, `processPendingChanges` changes the state of the current object graph.  `save` will save the current object graph to disk.

Calling `save` will call `processPendingChanges` automatically.

If you think of a text file in a word processor, `save` is analogous to saving the document to disk.

`processPendingChanges` is analogous to telling the word processor to update it's internal state of the document after an edit, but without saving to disk.  This usually triggers updates to the UI such as updating a displayed word or line count, doing any necessary formatting, etc...

In my experience, for the iPhone, you rarely need `processPendingChanges.`  I believe it is mostly intended for Mac OS X and handling advanced or complicated undo management or updating UI bindings.

For the iPhone, this is usually done to trigger NSFetchedResultsControllers to update table views.  Even then, this is somewhat rare.  If you aren't sure just stick with `save`

For more info, go study the difference between `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification` in the docs.